# output function was empty after being created to print out data

Tags: c

http://ideone.com/u0bVy

the link above contain the code that i wrote for a class project.I have a question about the output file for this code.The output file was created but was empty why is this happen ? 
I don't see anything wrong with the output function.Could it be that I did something wrong in the other functions? 
thank you 
here is the data for the code

```
LYSACEK Evan 
1  7.5 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3
2 10.0 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 0 1 1 1
3 3.0 1 2 2 2 1 0 1 2 1 1 1 2
4 3.1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0
5 1.7-3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3
6 2.1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
7 3.1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1
8 3.5 0 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1
WEIR Johnny
1 7.5 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1
2 10.0 1 1 1 1 2 0 1 1 1 1 2 1
3 3.0 1 1 1 2 1 0 1 1 2 2 2 2
4 3.1 1 2 1 2 1 1 0 0 2 1 1 0
5 5.5 0 -1 0 -1 -1 0 -1 -1 1 -2 -2 -2
6 1.3 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 2
7 3.1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 2 1 1 1
8 3.0 -1 1 1 2 1 0 1 0 2 1 -1 1
PLUSHENKO Evgeni
1 13.0 0 2 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 
2 7.5 1 2 2 2 2 1 2 1 2 2 2 2
3 6.0 2 1 1 1 1 0 0 2 1 2 1 2
4 2.3 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1
5 3.4 2 2 2 2 1 2 3 3 2 3 2 1
6 2.1 1 1 1 2 2 0 0 0 1 2 1 1
7 3.1 1 0 2 2 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 1
8 3.5 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 1
SAVOIE Matthew 
1 3.0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -1
2 7.5 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2
3 9.5 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
4 3.1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0
5 1.9  -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3
6 2.1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1
7 3.1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 2 0 2 1 
8 3.0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: please focus the problem to a specific part and post the relevant code here

Comment: well i specify problem is  in the output function though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to close `fpOut` file handle using [`fclose`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fclose/). Otherwise the content might not be written to disk before your program finishes.

Hints:

1. Do you have permission to write to `"output.txt"`
2. Have you tried using `fpOut = stdout;` just to check that the output is printed on the console.

---

### Output:

*On my system, running your code with your input.*

```
NAME:      LAB#6      EMAIL: 

EVENT: MEN SHORT PROGRAM
CHIEF ACCOUNTANT: 

SKATER: LUSHENKO Evgeni


[BASE]                   [SCORE]                        [TOTAL]
---------------------------------------------------------------
13.00     1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   10.17
 7.50     2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   10.17
 6.00     3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   10.17
 2.30     4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   10.17
 3.40     5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   10.17
 2.10     6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   10.17
 3.10     7   7   7   7   7   7   7   7   7   7   7   7   10.17
 3.50     8   8   8   8   8   8   8   8   8   8   8   8   10.17
---------------------------------------------------------------
Total Base: 40.90                  Total Technical Score: 63.82


SKATER: EIR Johnny


[BASE]                   [SCORE]                        [TOTAL]
---------------------------------------------------------------
 7.50     1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1    6.33
10.00     2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2    6.33
 3.00     3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3    6.33
 3.10     4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4    6.33
 5.50     5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5    6.33
 1.30     6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6    6.33
 3.10     7   7   7   7   7   7   7   7   7   7   7   7    6.33
 3.00     8   8   8   8   8   8   8   8   8   8   8   8    6.33
---------------------------------------------------------------
Total Base: 36.50                  Total Technical Score: 54.83


SKATER: YSACEK Evan 


[BASE]                   [SCORE]                        [TOTAL]
---------------------------------------------------------------
 7.50     1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   10.17
10.00     2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   10.17
 3.00     3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   10.17
 3.10     4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   10.17
 1.70     5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   10.17
 2.10     6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   10.17
 3.10     7   7   7   7   7   7   7   7   7   7   7   7   10.17
 3.50     8   8   8   8   8   8   8   8   8   8   8   8   10.17
---------------------------------------------------------------
Total Base: 34.00                  Total Technical Score: 53.58


SKATER: AVOIE Matthew 


[BASE]                   [SCORE]                        [TOTAL]
---------------------------------------------------------------
 3.00     1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1    6.33
 7.50     2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2    6.33
 9.50     3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3    6.33
 3.10     4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4    6.33
 1.90     5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5    6.33
 2.10     6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6    6.33
 3.10     7   7   7   7   7   7   7   7   7   7   7   7    6.33
 3.00     8   8   8   8   8   8   8   8   8   8   8   8    6.33
---------------------------------------------------------------
Total Base: 33.20                  Total Technical Score: 50.28
```

Comment: thank but that mean that the code isn't right. It is not printing out the right data

Comment: What do you mean? It's the exact same code and input that you posted. Please post the correct code then... it's much easier to help you then!

Comment: no i mean it does not print the score right as you can see the data for score of the output file is different from my input data, but that would be fixable as i can see the output now. Thank for posting the output

Comment: That wasn't the question and is, as you point out, fixable as you now has the method of seeing the output. *(Just a side note, the question would probably have been closed as "too localized" if your question had been "please fix this my program".)*

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing your problem stems from the misunderstanding of working of [`sscanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sscanf/). When you use `sscanf` the buffer pointer which it is reading is *not moved further* i.e. multiply calls will read the same buffer the same way. In your function `getData` the following piece of code:

```
        for(k = 0; k < MAX_ELEM; k++)
        {                       
                if(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer)-1, fpIn) != NULL)
            {                    
                        sscanf(buffer,"%d %f", &skater[i].elements, &skater[i].baseval[k]);
                        for(j = 0; j < SCORE; j++)
                        {
                                sscanf(buffer,"%d", &skater[i].score[k][j]);
                        }
                }
        }
```

the value read in `skater[i].elements` is stored in all of `skater[i].score[k][j]` values as the `skater[i].elements` will be the first `int` read (assuming that the call is successful). You could choose to read all the elements in a single `sscanf` call something on these (inelegant) lines:

```
    for (k = 0; k < MAX_ELEM; k++) {
        if (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1, fpIn) != NULL) 
        {
            sscanf(buffer, "%d %f %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d",
                &skater[i].elements,
                &skater[i].baseval[k],
                &skater[i].score[k][0],
                &skater[i].score[k][1],
                &skater[i].score[k][2],
                &skater[i].score[k][3],
                &skater[i].score[k][4],
                &skater[i].score[k][5],
                &skater[i].score[k][6],
                &skater[i].score[k][7],
                &skater[i].score[k][8],
                &skater[i].score[k][9],
                &skater[i].score[k][10],
                &skater[i].score[k][11]
                );
        }
    }
```

Or you could also look into [`fscanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fscanf/) for reading from file.
Side note: In `printData` you should exit if `fopen` fails. And you can use [`perror`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/perror/) for more meaning error messages when `fopen` fails.
Hope this helps!